# How WriteFile function interacts with another data on disk?

Tags: c#, c++, file-io, pinvoke

I using [WriteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365747(v=vs.85).aspx) function for writing sectors on disk. How WriteFile function interacts with another data on drive or disk? How I can write file without accidentally removing another file? And is it possible that the operating system can accidentally remove my file?

Comment: Need context. Give us some code to show how you're getting the handle that you pass to `WriteFile`. What you're doing is either harmless or extremely dangerous. But we can't tell which unless you show us how you're using it.

Answer (score 4):

When you write directly to the disk you are bypassing the file system completely. Unless you re-implement the functionality required to read and respect the file system then you can expect to destroy the disk. You will likely not only write over other files, but it is likely that you will overwrite the meta data – that is the information that describes the structure and location of the directories and files, their attributes and so on.

If the disk already contains a functioning file system and you don't want to disturb that then there is practically no scenario that I can imagine where it makes sense to write to the disk directly. If you want to write files to the disk, do just that. I suspect that you have made a mistake in your reasoning somewhere that has led you to believe that you should be writing directly to the disk.

Comment: I can't see that `WriteFile()` should write to disk directly. Your answer may just confuse the OP of what they're actually doing.

Comment: It's not that he is using WriteFile, it's that he is saying that he is writing *sectors on disk*

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ the confusion is yours I think. I understand the question fine.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan May be you're right. The question is pretty unclear, about OP is using `WriteFile()` to write to a raw disk device directly, or just uses a simple file handle.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ The question is clear enough. It talks about writing sectors directly to the disk. That's clear. What made you think the question is about writing to files rather than direct to the disk.  I don't understand why my answer was downvoted.

Comment: @panta, You're correct in that, but usually people tend to use some higher level function than WriteFile() when they're actually writing to *files*. In my opinion, that's a funny choice for the function's name by Microsoft. But I sort of like that, especially as Microsoft's OS is the one that traditionally *hasn't* represented just about anything accessible as a *file*... :D Or maybe it's because *finally* everything *can* now be accessed as a file.... someone shut me up now please.

Answer (score 2):

Do you really write *sectors on disk* and not to a *file on disk*? Some background information would have been great, because if you are really writing into the raw disk surface instead of writing to a file on the disk, through the operating system, using higher level functions such as fopen(), fwrite(), or even higher that that, then you should be doing it for a good reason. Might we inquire as to what that reason is?

If you are writing disk sectors with no regards as to what filesystem the disk has, then all bets are off. Supposing that the operating system allows that, there's nothing to protect you from overwriting critical disk data or from the OS overwriting your files.

I've done that to access numbered sectors on an embedded system whose only contact to the "outside world" (the PC) was a custom hacked USB mass storage interface. And even then I broke cold sweat every time I had to do it - If my code would have accidentally written to the hard disk of the PC, it would have probably been good-bye to the OS installation on the hard disk and all the files written to it.